# UDP File Transfer Java

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I know UDP is not reliable and should not be used to send files but I have been asked to do that inside of a small part of an application for a small college assignment. For some reason my application freezes when I run the code to upload a file from client to server. Could anyone please help tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Client:

```
String hostName = hostNameTxt.getText();
    String portAsString = portNumTxt.getText();
    int portNum = Integer.parseInt(portAsString);      
    String sentFilePath = "c:/Documents/test.txt";
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    ServerSocket servsock = null;
    Socket sock = null;
    try {
    servsock = new ServerSocket(portNum);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Waiting...");
        try {
        sock = servsock.accept(); //failing here I think
        System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);
        // send file
        File myFile = new File (sentFilePath);
        byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
        fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
        os = sock.getOutputStream();
        System.out.println("Sending " + sentFilePath + "(" + mybytearray.length + " bytes)");
        os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
        os.flush();
        System.out.println("Done.");
        }
        finally {
        if (bis != null) bis.close();
        if (os != null) os.close();
        if (sock!=null) sock.close();
        }
    }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Client1Interface.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println(ex);
    }        finally {
    if (servsock != null) try {
        servsock.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Client1Interface.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }
```

Server:

```
String recievedFilePath = "c:/Documents/source.txt";
    String hostName = "localhost";
    int portNum = 7;
    int fileSize = 6022386;
    try{
        int bytesRead;
    int current = 0;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    Socket sock = null;
    try {
    sock = new Socket(hostName, portNum);
    System.out.println("Connecting...");

  // receive file
    byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [fileSize];
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    fos = new FileOutputStream(recievedFilePath);
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
    current = bytesRead;

    do {
        bytesRead =
            is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
        if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
    } while(bytesRead > -1);

    bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
    bos.flush();
    System.out.println("File " + recievedFilePath
        + " downloaded (" + current + " bytes read)");
    }
    finally {
    if (fos != null) fos.close();
    if (bos != null) bos.close();
    if (sock != null) sock.close();
    }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
         ex.printStackTrace( );
         System.out.println("Error Uploading File");
    }
```

Comment: What's the exception you get when it crashes?

Comment: No exception seems to appear, the application just freezes

Comment: This code is full of WTFs. Why does your client use a `ServerSocket` and call `accept` instead of the server? Why don't you use catch with resources? Why don't you check the return code of `read`? Why does the server code have a hard-coded file size?

Comment: Sockets are TCP and not UDP...

Comment: Now what, does it crash or freeze? That is a difference! Be precise! Include any errors. Also check the server logs. If it only freezes, where does that happen? Use a debugger.

Comment: Where is it frozen? @Michael-O There are also UDP sockets.

Comment: Sorry I should have said freezes instead of crashes. I used some print statements to see that it seems to freeze on the client side after the second try where I have the comment "//failing here I think"

Comment: @immibis, the sockets used in that code is TCP.

Comment: As you have been told to use UDP, the behaviour of this TCP code is irrelevant. Throw it all away and start again wiith UDP. NB among numerous errors your client is a server and your server is a client, but it's immaterial.

Comment: My censure to all the down and closing votes in this question. The OP has made a clear question (why his/her code is not working as expected), has shown a certain researching effort, has posted a minimal and verifiable example, and has been providing feedback through the comments. OK, it is clearly a question with a bunch of errata and concept errors, but if we want to point them out, we must provide an **answer**, not a downvote, or else he/she will never learn, and that's way he/she as come to SO.

Comment: @LittleSanti The OP has stated he is supposed to be writing UDP code, so all the TCP code he has posted is rrelevant, whether it works or not. You can't provide an answer to a question that doesn't make sense. Of course if you think you can do so, don't let us stop you.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use another port. The IP port 7 is blocked for the echo service, which will simply send you the same data back.

You should use ports above 1024. Otherwise you need superuser right from you OS to use this port.

The naming of you app is a little bit confusing. Normally the server should provide a ServerSocket on a not already used port and listen. The client must connect with a regular Socket to this port and send the data.

Comment: Yeah I based it off of an example I found online so sorry for the poor naming. I tried changing the port number to 1024 but that didn't seem to work. I need to be able to change the port number to one of my choosing as well

Comment: @Niall Don't apologize. Just fix it. You picked a very poor source even for TCP, and for UDP it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing your program (both server and client running in the same host), and it **works**. Still, I've to warn you about some important details (basically all of them have been already told in comments):

### Conceptual details

- The APIs chosen (`java.net.Socket` and `java.net.ServerSocket`) are **TCP socket implementations**, and not UDP. The UPD APIs are `java.net.DatagramSocket` and `java.net.DatagramPacket`.
- The first program is no doubt the **server**, and the second is the **client**.

### Technical details

- You have to start first the server, and then, the client.
- Server and client must run on different JVMs, so you have to run each one on a **different process**, either in a command shell or either by running it from your IDE.
- (as Lars Repenning said) You have to use any available port over 1024, for example 3000.

### Minor technical details

- Do not allocate a buffer as big as the file size. To write the data out to a File, you should use the buffering technique: Use a small buffer (4096 bytes or multiple) and on each iteration, fill it with `InputStream.read` and write it with `OutputStream.write`. You will avoid memory problems and also will save yourself the need to know a priori the file size.